# How to get green bug (debug) icon on a stored procedure?

Tags: debugging, oracle10g, toad

I have Oracle 10.5 installed on my system.

I created a stored procedure using Toad. It is running successfully.

I observed that there are different icons for stored procedures in Toad:

1. Red cross (error in procedure)
2. White rectangle (new procedure)
3. Green bug (debugged procedure)

My procedure has the *white rectangle* icon. I want to change it to the *green bug* icon.

I found online that I have to run the stored procedure in debug mode. I ran it but it didn't change the icon.

How I can get the *green bug* icon for my stored procedure?

Answer (score 3):

The *green bug* indicates that the stored procedure (or package) was compiled with debug information and can be debugged. In order to create the necessary debug information, you need to (re-)compile your stored procedure with

```
alter procedure PROCNAME compile debug;
```

Replace `PROCNAME` with the actual name of your stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

When using the **Schema Browser**, you can right-click on your procedure and select **"Compile with Debug"** from the context menu.

[image: Procedure Context Menu Illustration]

For packages, the context menu item is **"Compile" > "Compile with Debug"**.

[image: Package Context Menu Illustration]

If a dialog box opens asking to choose *Refresh Mode*, you can leave the default option **"Refresh items one by one"** on, unless otherwise required.